# C: how to manage a large structure?

Tags: c, structure, heap-memory

In C:

I am trying to use a structure containing a large array, and I have a stack overflow error while declaring it. I guess (correctly?) that I don't have enough memory in the stack, and therefore, I should use the heap (I don't want to change my stack memory size, as the code will be used by others). Could anyone show me a way to do it simply? Or should I use something else than a structure?

My code - definitions.h:

```
#define a_large_number 100000

struct std_calibrations{
    double E[a_large_number];
};
```

My code - main.c:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    /* ...
    */

    // Stack overflows here:
    struct std_calibrations calibration;

    /* ...
    */

    return (0);
}
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: `static struct std_calibrations calibration;`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A couple of options:

1. Use [`malloc(3)`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/malloc/) and [`free(3)`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/free/) to dynamically allocate your structure at runtime.  This option is what you're talking about when you say you "should use the heap."

   ```
   struct std_calibrations *calibration = malloc(sizeof *calibration);
   ```

   and later,

   ```
   free(calibration);
   ```
2. Give the structure static storage duration.  Either add a `static` keyword or make it global.  This option may change some semantics about how you use the structure, but given your example code, it should be fine.

Comment: Thanks. After struggling a little, I declared my structure as global and it works. I'll come back to your solution later to improve my code, but right now, I am glad it works.

Answer (score 4):

Change the member `E` to be a `double*` and `malloc()` memory for it:

```
struct std_calibrations calibration;
calibration->E = malloc(sizeof(*calibration->E) * a_large_number);
```

and remember to `free(calibration->E);` when no longer required. It would be possible to extend `struct std_calibrations`, if desired, to contain the number of elements in `E` so a user of `struct std_calibrations` could decide how many elements they require.